# load HTML elements conditionally before DOM ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to apply Access Control on web application. I have an array AllowedElementsArray which contains names of elements. I want to add only allowed elements into DOM before DOM ready.

```
//my array
var AllowedElementsArray = ['textbox','button','radioButton'];

// HTML elements
<body>
    Name: <input type='text' class='textbox'/>
    Task: <input type='text' />
    Hola: <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'/>
    Hello: <input type='radio'/>
    Foo: <input type='radio' class='radioButton'/>
    Bar: <input type='button' class='button'/>
</body>

// after DOM is ready only these elements should be shown
Name: <input type='text' class='textbox'/>
Foo: <input type='radio' class='radioButton'/>
Bar: <input type='button' class='button'/>
```

or is there any other efficient way, because my HTML is dense, have too many elements.

Comment: `I want to add only allowed elements into DOM before DOM ready.` That's a bit of an oxymoron. You're effectively asking 'how can I amend the DOM before the DOM can be amended?'.

Comment: i'd like to point out that this won't be great for access control as anything you do will have to be client side (if you want this to be done after the DOM has loaded)- something you don't have full control over.

Comment: Do it server-side. This is not a client-side task.You are still transferring your "too many elements" across the wire at the moment (or Ajax the required data after page load)

Comment: @Rory Sorry for improper wording, but i hope you get the idea what i wanna do.

Comment: Appreciate the idea to do this on server-side. but how will i send HTML from server to client? element by element or whole chunk of allowed elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are very particular about having access control then I would suggest you to generate the HTML from server side, Else if you want to do on client side then the client can manipulate no matter what.

---

### Jquery Approach

Anyways doing this on client side can be done as suggested below.
Also here is a **[Working Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/uLLp1bw3/3/)**

change your HTML to so its easy to remove the unwanted elements when its wrapped around a `span`

```
<div id="elements">
  <span>Name:<input type='text' class='textbox' /></span>
  <span>Task:<input type='text' /></span>
  <span>Hola:<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' /></span>
  <span>Hello:<input type='radio' /></span>
  <span>Foo:<input type='radio' class='radioButton' /></span>
  <span>Bar:<input type='button' class='button' /></span>
</div>
```

And the below script, I have used  **[$.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)** to check if the elements class exists in the array.

```
var AllowedElementsArray = ['textbox', 'button', 'radioButton'];

$(function() {
  $.each($('#elements input'), function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var shouldBeRetained = $.inArray($input.attr('class'), AllowedElementsArray);
    if (shouldBeRetained == -1) { // -1 is given when the class is not found in the array
      $input.parent().remove();
    }   
  });

  $('body').show();
});
```

Also have this styles, So the idea is to initially hide the `body` untill we have removed the unwanted elements. One our scripts are done executing we can show the `body`

```
body{
  display:none;
}
```

---

### MVC Approach

**Edit:** Since you said you are using MVC, You can do this without Jquery, All you have to do is add `if` checks on all your input controls. One thing to be clear is what ever c# code you write in the `.cshtml` file is server side, That is the MVC framework executes all the code in the `.cshtml` file and the final result will be plain HTML,Javascript(if any), Css (if any) which is returned as a response to the browser. You will not see razor or a c# syntax in your view page in the browser. So as all the information out there in the internet mentions *`data is sent from controller to view`*, its not totally right.. Data is passed from controller to a method named `View()` which will fetch the respective `.cshtml` file and processes it and the end result is passed to the Browser (which is pure HTML and not .cshtml). So once you are clear with this your problem can be solves as below.

in your controller add the array of visible type into a Viewbag;

```
ViewBag.AllowedElements = ["textbox", "button", "radioButton"];
```

Now in your view at the top add this code block and assign the ViewBag data into a variable.

```
@{
   var allowedElements = ViewBag.AllowedElements;
 }
```

Now add a if check to all your input elements.

```
<div id="elements">
  @if(allowedElements.Contains("textbox")){
    <span>Name:<input type='text' class='textbox' /></span>
  }
  @if(allowedElements.Contains("text")){
    <span>Task:<input type='text' /></span>
  }
  @if(allowedElements.Contains("checkbox")){
    <span>Hola:<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' /></span>
  }
  @if(allowedElements.Contains("text")){
    <span>Hello:<input type='radio' /></span>
  }
  @if(allowedElements.Contains("radioButton")){
    <span>Foo:<input type='radio' class='radioButton' /></span>
   }
  @if(allowedElements.Contains("button")){
     <span>Bar:<input type='button' class='button' /></span>
  }
</div>
```

This way only the elements that satisfies the `if` check is sent to the browser and is cleaner way than doing it in Jquery.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah, i think generating HTML from server side would be better. but what if i have tens of HTML files in my application. how can i port them to server-side. FYI im using MVC architecture and C# on server-side. JQuery, AngularJS on client side.

Comment: @Shaybi Sorry I missed to give you more inputs for solving this issue..IF you are using MVC then spot on.. you have great chance of doing this right... as mentioned in server side code.. Let me know if you need it..

Comment: Sure @Reddy , i'm using MVC5. i'll appreciate if you guide me to do this on server side.

Comment: @Shaybi I added MVC approach to the answer.. Upvote if you liek it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

But if you can do this server side though, it would be better.  No point in sending HTML down to the client if it's not needed..

```js
$(function () {
  var cls = AllowedElementsArray.map(
    function (r) { return '.' + r }).join(',');
  $(cls).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>var AllowedElementsArray = ['textbox','button','radioButton'];</script>

<body>
    <div class="hidden textbox">Name: <input type='text'/></div>
    <div class="hidden">Task: <input type='text'/></div>
    <div class="checkbox hidden">Hola: <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox hidden'/></div>
    <div class="hidden radio">Hello: <input type='radio hidden'/></div>
    <div class="hidden radioButton">Foo: <input type='radio'/></div>
    <div class="hidden button">Bar: <input type='button'/></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just loop your array and check for elements that match the class. Then show/hide as appropriate. I have wrapped each element and its label in `div` elements so that the text and the element can be hidden or shown as a single unit. No JQuery necessary.

```js
var AllowedElementsArray = ['textbox','button','radioButton'];

// Get node-list of all the input elements in the page:
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

// Loop through the elements
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i){
  // Check to see if the input has a class matching the AllowedElementsArray
  // If so, show it. Otherwise, hide it. 
  if(AllowedElementsArray.indexOf(inputs[i].getAttribute("class")) > -1){
    inputs[i].parentElement.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    inputs[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<div>Name: <input type='text' class='textbox'/></div>
<div>Task: <input type='text' /></div>
<div>Hola: <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'/></div>
<div>Hello: <input type='radio'/></div>
<div>Foo: <input type='radio' class='radioButton'/></div>
<div>Bar: <input type='button' class='button'/></div>
```